# How to put ESP32 to sleep until next scheduled wake-up time with RTC module

Tags: c++, arduino-esp32

I have a problem with the Arduino program below. I have an RTC module that gives me real-time clock. The goal is to put the ESP32 to sleep until the next scheduled wake-up time. The problem is that the ESP32 wakes up correctly the first time at the scheduled time, but after that, it instantly wakes up around forty times before actually going to sleep until the next wake-up. This is not always the case, but after the first wake-up, the ESP32 no longer respects the next wake-up time and wakes up inexplicably. There is likely an issue with the timing or a misplaced condition.

```cpp
#include "BluetoothA2DPSink.h"
BluetoothA2DPSink Pillow;

//librairies pr le module RTC
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ds3231.h>

// VolumeChanged doesnt work
int volume = 0;
void volumeChanged(int newVolume) {
    //Serial.println(newVolume);//ecriture du volume dans le port serie
    volume = newVolume;
}

//Automatic shut down if no music
esp_a2d_connection_state_t last_state;
uint16_t minutes = 1;//here after 1 minute
unsigned long shutdown_ms = millis() + 1000 * 60 * minutes;

void on_data() {
  shutdown_ms = millis() + 1000 * 60 * minutes; 
}

//wakeup from deep sleep by puching a bouton
const int bouton = 33;//pin gpio33 de l'esp32
const int buzzer = 27;//buzzer

//reveil avec horloge RTC
struct ts temps;
#define HOUR 10//////creation d'une heure/////
#define MINUTE 30//////fictive de test////////
int time_hour_diff = 0;
int time_minute_diff = 0;
int time_diff = 0;

void reveil_RTC(){
    DS3231_get(&temps);

    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
      //pour les heures
      if(HOUR == temps.hour && MINUTE < temps.min) {
        time_hour_diff = 23;       
      } 
      else if(HOUR == temps.hour && MINUTE > temps.min || HOUR - temps.hour == 1) {
        time_hour_diff = 0;      
      }
      else if(HOUR < temps.hour){
        time_hour_diff = 24 - temps.hour + HOUR;      
      } 
      else if(HOUR > temps.hour){
        time_hour_diff = HOUR - temps.hour;     
      }
      //pour les minutes    
      if(MINUTE > temps.min){
        time_minute_diff = MINUTE - temps.min;    
      }
      else if(MINUTE < temps.min){
        time_minute_diff = 60 - temps.min + MINUTE;
      }
      else if(MINUTE == temps.min){
        time_minute_diff = 0;   
      }      
    }
    time_diff = time_hour_diff * 3600 + time_minute_diff * 60;   
    Serial.print("Reveil dans "); Serial.print(time_hour_diff); Serial.print("h"); Serial.print(time_minute_diff); //Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print(", il est "); Serial.print(temps.hour); Serial.print("h"); Serial.print(temps.min); 
    Serial.print(" et le reveil sonnera dans "); Serial.print(time_diff); Serial.print(" secondes"); Serial.print("\n");   
}

//choix du wakeUp
#define wake_up 1//0 = wakeup bouton, 1 = wakeup RTC.

void wake_up_choice() {
  switch (wake_up) {
    case 0: 
      esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_33, 0); 
      break;
    case 1: 
      esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(time_diff*1000000); 
      break;
  }
}

// for esp_a2d_audio_state_t see https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_a2dp.html#_CPPv421esp_a2d_audio_state_t
void audio_state_changed(esp_a2d_audio_state_t state, void* ptr) {
    Serial.println(Pillow.to_str(state));//ecriture de l'etat de l'audio dans le port serie
}

// for esp_a2d_connection_state_t see https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_a2dp.html#_CPPv426esp_a2d_connection_state_t
void connection_state_changed(esp_a2d_connection_state_t state, void* ptr) {
    //Serial.println(Pillow.to_str(state));//ecriture de l'etat de connexion bluetooth dans le port serie
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin();
    DS3231_init(DS3231_INTCN);
    //DS3231_get(&temps);
    unsigned long shutdown_ms = millis() + 1000 * 60 * minutes;
    pinMode(bouton, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);

    const i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX | I2S_MODE_DAC_BUILT_IN),
        .sample_rate = 44100, // corrected by info from bluetooth
        .bits_per_sample = (i2s_bits_per_sample_t)16, /* the DAC module will only take the 8bits from MSB */
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
        .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_MSB,
        .intr_alloc_flags = 0, // default interrupt priority
        .dma_buf_count = 8,
        .dma_buf_len = 64,
        .use_apll = false
    };
    
    if(wake_up == 1){
      Serial.print("RTC timer wakeup activate\n");
    } 
    else{
      Serial.print("Ext0 wakeup activate\n");
    }
    
    Pillow.set_i2s_config(i2s_config);
    Pillow.set_on_volumechange(volumeChanged);
    Pillow.set_on_connection_state_changed(connection_state_changed);
    Pillow.set_on_audio_state_changed(audio_state_changed);
    Pillow.set_on_data_received(on_data);    
    Pillow.start("PILLOW");
    
    tone(buzzer, 400);
    delay(1000);
    noTone(buzzer);
    delay(700);
    tone(buzzer, 400);
    delay(1000);
    noTone(buzzer);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  //version de chatgpt
  if(currentMillis > shutdown_ms){
    // stop the processor
    reveil_RTC();
    Serial.println("Shutting down...");
    wake_up_choice();
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
  }

  // check state every second
  if(currentMillis % 1000 == 0){
    esp_a2d_connection_state_t state = Pillow.get_connection_state();
    if(last_state != state){
      bool is_connected = state == ESP_A2D_CONNECTION_STATE_CONNECTED;
      Serial.println(is_connected ? "Connected" : "Not connected");    
      last_state = state;
    }
    reveil_RTC();
  }
}
```

I tried to fix that restart issue by remove and add conditions in the main void loop() but the results still the the same with no warranty of good execution about what I want

Answer (score 0):

`int time_diff` might overflow when multiplying some number by 1'000'000. Especially since it's multiplied from hours (3'600'000'000; already overflows) and minutes (60'000'000).

Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C++. Anything might happen.

Use a 64 bit number like `uint64_t`, which is the type of the parameter to `esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup()` anyways. You are already using `uint16_t`, so I think you know what `uint64_t` means.

Why does it overflow? Well, the first number is an `int` and `1000000` is also an int. That makes the result an `int`. After it overflowed, it will be converted to the parameter type `uint64_t`.

Note that `long` is only 4 bytes on the ESP32 and thus not better than `int`.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your quick response. It seems fair so I'll try it and keep you aware, thanks again

Comment: That's it @thomas weller, you were right. It was the variable that was causing some trouble. Thanks so much